# 3d Touch Alternative in Ios App

Tags: ios, swift3

I am developing an ios app. Where i need to give options under 3d touch menu.When the user do long hard press (same as 3d touch) then the menu will be popped up to show different options. But what to do if the old iphone without 3d touch is using my app. What alternative options should be given
A simple alert message with options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the good ideas is to do a long press. So instead of hard press on the screen, user can hold his finger on the object. :)